# I have a python script which needs to update a sqlite database,but it's not working,and i am not getting any error

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

```
def depositamt():

    conn = sqlite3.connect("atm.db")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('''UPDATE data SET balance = balance + '%s' WHERE username = '%s' '''%(depositamount.get(),username.get()))

    messagebox.showinfo("Successful", "deposit amount successfully")

    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

This function gets the username from username Entry box and updates the record. But the database is not being updated.

Comment: Use [parametrized queries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor) to prevent sql injection attack. It's important. Learn how then make it a habit. What are you expecting from this: `depositammount.get()`? The only `get` method that I am familiar with is the dict method and it requires one argument. All things being equal, that line will error. Maybe the function is never called.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure about your syntax?

It is not the syntax I am familiar with. Assuming both functions work as expected and username is already present into your base I would use the following statement:

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE data SET balance=? WHERE username=?", (depositamount.get(), username.get()))
```

Regards.

Comment: cursor.execute("UPDATE data SET balance=? WHERE username=?", (depositammount.get(), username.get()))                                                                       by using this statement it is not working.  but when i remove WHERE username=? or WHERE username= '%s'  , it's working  but updating all records of the table

Comment: That means the user name is absent from the database. And can’t be updated therefore.

Comment: It would be useful to check at first by a SELECT statement.

Comment: cursor.execute("SELECT count(\*) FROM data WHERE username=?", (username.get(),)). Then (count,) = cursor.fetchone(). Then run an **INSERT** statement or an **UPDATE** statement depending on *count*.